# MySQL select SUM with LIMIT AND WHERE

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select the SUM of a few values with a limit of 2. I've seen a couple of example of this (9877872) but have been unable to get it working. I have

```
SELECT SUM(points) 
FROM 
(SELECT points FROM user_table 
WHERE city=1 AND group =5)  
AS min_points ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 2
```

However the limit clause at the end of the query does not seem to be executed and I just get the sum of all the users in the table...

Would anyone know what I'm doing wrong...?

Comment: It is not very clear what result you expect. 

The subquery returns a list of the number of points of the users of city 1 and group 5. The outer query simpy calculates the sum. 

So you get the total points of all users with city = 1 and group = 5.

Comment: The sum returns only one line, because the query misses a group by statement. Your question is not clear about what you want to group by. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    SELECT SUM(points) 
FROM 
(SELECT points FROM user_table 
WHERE city=1 AND group =5 ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 2)  AS t1
```

Comment: I've tried this too but get the following error   _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1248, 'Every derived table must have its own alias')